# Why semi/nonparametric models?

Tags: bayesian, nonparametric, hierarchical-bayesian, nonparametric-bayes

Increasing the flexibility of models makes it prone to overfitting. On the other hand, it looks to me that, if the space function classes $\mathcal{F}$ is too big, it is hard to prove bounds on empirical risks bounds and that sort of stuff. That's why I am questioning the necessity/importance/applicability of non-parametric models.

Here by nonparametrics I mostly mean, Dirichlet Processes and Beta Processes (and related family).

Any comments?

Comment: I don't know why this is tagged with Bayesian - most research in nonparametric methods is frequentist. And isn't the success of the SVM an argument that we can do nonparametric stuff with provable empirical risk bounds? Neural nets are also, in spirit, nonparametric models (universal approximation theorem) with some clever regularization schemes, and these are state-of-the-art for many problems.

Comment: Now that you've edited, it's apparent this is about Bayesian nonparametrics, rather than the other 90% of nonparametrics. Associated with each BNP model is usually some story about the data similar to a parametric model, and they tend to do well when the story they tell makes sense. For a success story, just look at HDP; variations on HDP are very close to state-of-the-art for topic modeling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first sentence is not necessarily correct. First off, an increase in numbers of parameters does indeed increase the degrees of freedom and the standard errors of point estimates (hence their degree of generalization). An example of this is the nested classes of Exponential and Weibull models. It's not universally agreed upon that "model complexity" necessarily means the parameter space, though, but it is a good place to start for discussion.

Semiparametric and nonparametric inference make overfitting a nonissue by generalizing the likelihood function into a new type of function where such extraneous parameters are ancillary. The only caveat is that the statistician has to correctly identify such models. Examples of such extended likelihoods are conditional likelihood (in mixed modeling), partial likelihood (in Cox models), pseudo likelihood (forgetting some applications for that...), profile likelihood, quasilikelihood, (and the list goes on). The parameter spaces for such likelihoods are seen as *projections* of high (possibly infinte) dimensional (compact) parameter spaces.

It's only in fully parametric inference where every causal relationship needs to be specified, such as the correlation structure for teeth within a mouth, or the correlation between failure times in a prospective cohort among denominators of individuals counted more than once. Many of these likelihoods are overly complex or intractable hence inference about them is non-existent or otherwise not popular.

Modeling processes is a fully parametric endeavor. You must be able to simulate data from an estimated data generating mechanism. SP/NP often cannot achieve this. Neither can the produce fitted effects nor can they claim to simulate realizations from any data generating process. SP/NP focuses on the point estimation of a specific parameter and efficiently calculates estimates and standard errors for that parameter cancelling out all other parameters in the data generating process through either conditioning, estimating them as nuisance parameters, or some other process.

SP/NP inference examples are the log-rank test (NP), the plain vanilla asymptotic t-test without normality assumptions (NP), conditional logistic regression (SP), generalized estimating equations (GEE), and Cox proportional hazards models (SP).

Examples where semi-parametric inference breaks down is in the case of missing at random data (as opposed to missing completely at random data), where the value of some observed outcome or covariate depends on the things which we deemed to be ancillary (such as informative censoring in Cox models). A fully likelihood based survival analysis would require separate models (and their correlation) for survival and censoring outcomes.

Comment: This is a very classical perspective. Personally, I'd be fine with calling RBMs or ANNs "nonparametric" but you certainly can simulate from them. Ditto for Bayesian nonparametric methods.

Comment: You have a source or reasoning for why those machine learning techniques are nonparametric? They're not really used for inference, so I don't even see how that enters the equation.

Comment: Bayesian nonparametric has nonparametric right there in the name (formally, we put a prior on the space of cdfs which has large support) and is used for inference all the time. To simulate we can just draw the measure from the posterior. OP is also likely from ML given that he is using Statistical Learning Theory lingo.

Comment: The ML models can be formalized as nonparametric using sieves (which to an extent is similar to how they are used) I think, combined with universal approximation I'd say nonparametric is a fine label.

Comment: I'm not being entirely disingenuous, but I am failing to draw an explanation for why things like activation thresholds, (or other estimable model terms) aren't conceived of as parameters? I use "nonparametric" as a modifier strictly in the context of inference. Exactly what would you be testing the hypothesis of when you fit such models?

Comment: "Nonparametric" doesn't typically mean "I have no parameters." Even in the simplest case of $X_1, \ldots, X_n \sim F$ where $F$ is an unspecified cdf, $F$ is just a parameter in the (infinite-dimensional) space of cdfs. A common definition of a nonparametric problem is one with an infinite-dimensional parameter space, and a method is nonparametric if it can estimate anything in that space. Then, the class of ANNs (with network topology a free parameter) fits this definition for nonparametric function estimation.

Comment: Partly agreed with @guy. Many people call a model "nonparametric" if the dimensionality (capacity/parameters/etc...) of the model expands as data grows. In that sense SVM is a nonparametric form. 
There some classes of ANN (not all of them) without previously define topology. In fact, their topology is also being inferred by data (this is usually called "automatic relevance determination"). In that sense ANN could be considered nonparametric.

Comment: I don't see what conducting inference has to do with a problem being nonparametric. If I want estimate an arbitrary function on $[0, 1]$, this is by all definitions I've read a nonparametric problem. I mean, if you want you can have as strict a definition of "nonparametric" as you like, but I think these days people are much looser with the term. Incidentally, Cox models and rank tests didn't even make it into Wasserman's "All of Nonparametric Statistics."

Comment: What are you saying to be nonparametric?!? Is it a density... a distribution... a random variable... Here you're talking about a Brownian Bridge, but just before RBM. I'm confused as all heck.

Comment: Never mentioned Brownian bridges, no idea where you got that from. What I'm saying is that estimating an arbitrary real valued function is a nonparametric problem regardless of what your goals are - see [this](http://www.amazon.com/All-Nonparametric-Statistics-Springer-Texts/dp/0387251456), or [this](http://www.amazon.com/Statistical-Learning-Adaptive-Processing-Communications/dp/0471030031), for example - and since ANNs with topology as a free parameter can solve this problem, it should be regarded as a nonparametric method.

Comment: Indeed both the texts you reference refer to nonparametrics strictly in the context of statistical inference.

Comment: Are you arguing that neither Wasserman nor Vapnik would consider ANNs to be nonparametric techniques? I'm confident enough that I would bet money that both would agree with me. Wasserman because he devotes most of his book to estimating arbitrary mean functions and densities - which Neural nets can do within a statistical framework - and Vapnik because he uses ANNs as a constant comparison to his SVM which I *know* he explicitly labels as nonparametric.

Comment: Wolfram also agrees with me. See [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NonparametricEstimation.html). Or just google "Neural network nonparametric" and look over the tons of papers that come up.

Comment: You are not forced to marginalize out some of the parameters.  For example the R `rms` package `orm` function handles semi-parametric ordinal regression models using full likelihood, allowing for thousands of intercepts in a computationally efficient way.