# What is the likelihood function of having heads 8 times out of 10 toss

Tags: bayesian, likelihood

## Question

What is the likelihood function for the event where 8 heads observed after 10 coin tossing?

Is below in Python/Scipy using ([scipy.stats.binom](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binom.html)) correct?

```
likelihood = []
for i in range(11):
    likelihood.append(binom.pmf(n=10,k=i,p=0.8))
```

For example, suppose the current probability distribution has the mean = 5 (fair coin/5 heads out of 10 toss). Then the Bayesian update will be:

```
likelihood = []
for i in range(11):
    likelihood.append(binom.pmf(n=10,k=i,p=0.8))

# first is prior, second is posterior
second = np.multiply(first, likelihood)
second = second / np.sum(second)
```

Is this correct?

[image]

## Background

(*I used 8 heads out of 10 above but the example below uses 4 heads out of 10. It was simply because 8 heads to 10 was far away from the prior. Apology for the confusion.*)

[Introduction to Bayesian statistics, part 1: The basic concepts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0F0QoMCSKJ4) says that Bayesian regression **posterior** is **prior x likelihood** and normalisation, and the likelihood function for coin toss is binominal(10, 4, $\theta$) for 4 heads out of 10 toss.
[image]

I am not clear about the **$p(y|\theta)$**. I think it is the probability distribution for the event **y** (4 heads out of 10) to happen under some condition $\theta$, but what is $\theta$? Kindly explain what $\theta$ and **$p(y|\theta)$** are in simple layman's English **without** mathematical formulas. In a way a grand-ma can understand.

As the event of **4 heads out of 10 toss** to happen will be independent from the prior events, I suppose the likelihood function will be the binomial distribution of the coin that has 40% chance to have head at 10 coin toss.

Is this correct? If not, please explain why and how to get $p(y|\theta)$.

### Code (Jupyter notebook)

```
import math
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import binom

import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline


x = np.linspace(0, 10, 11)
y = [0] * len(x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3,sharex=True,sharey=True)
fig.set_size_inches(20, 5)
# 

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# First
# 5 heads out of 10
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
first = []
for i in range(11):
    first.append(binom.pmf(n=10,k=i,p=0.5))

ax[0].grid(
    color='lightblue',
    linestyle='--',
    linewidth=0.5
)    
ax[0].plot(
    [5],
    [0],
    linestyle="None",
    marker='o',
    markersize=10,
    color='r'
)
ax[0].vlines(x=x, ymin=0, ymax=first, colors='b', linestyles='--', lw=2)
ax[0].set_title('Initial 5 out of 10 toss')

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# First + Second likelifood overlay
# Likelifood for having had 8 heads out of 10
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ax[1].grid(
    color='lightblue',
    linestyle='--',
    linewidth=0.5
)
ax[1].plot(
    [5, 8],
    [0 ,0],
    linestyle="None",
    marker='o',
    markersize=10,
    color='r'
)
likelihood = []
for i in range(11):
    likelihood.append(binom.pmf(n=10,k=i,p=0.8))

ax[1].vlines(x=x, ymin=0, ymax=likelihood, colors='r', linestyles='-', lw=2)
ax[1].vlines(x=x, ymin=0, ymax=first, colors='b', linestyles='--', lw=2)
ax[1].set_title('8 out of 10 toss observed')

second = np.multiply(first, likelihood)
second = second / np.sum(second)

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------\
# Posterior
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ax[2].grid(
    color='lightblue',
    linestyle='--',
    linewidth=0.5
)
ax[2].plot(
    [5, 8],
    [0 ,0],
    linestyle="None",
    marker='o',
    markersize=10,
    color='r'
)
ax[2].vlines(x=x, ymin=0, ymax=second, colors='k', linestyles='-', lw=1)
ax[2].set_title('5 and 8 out of 10 toss')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the code is not correct. The likelihood function for "the event where 8 heads observed after 10 coin tossing" is the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with $n=10$ and unknown probability of success $\theta$:

$$
y \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=10,\, p=\theta)
$$

this is your $p(y|\theta)$. Notice that this already is a distribution of all the tosses, not a single toss.

In your code you used `binom.pmf(n=10,k=i,p=0.8)`, so you *assumed* (or knew) $p$ to be $0.8$. This is not a likelihood, but rather a distribution of $y$ when all the parameters are known. Alternatively, maybe you wanted to show likelihood function evaluated on $p=0.8$ value, then this is the case.

*Likelihood* is a distribution of the data *given the* parameter $\theta$. *Prior* is the distribution of the unknown parameter $\theta$ that is assumed *a priori*, before seeing the data. In your code the `first` is, incorrectly, also a binomial distribution. The most common, "textbook", prior for $\theta$ is the [beta distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47771/what-is-the-intuition-behind-beta-distribution/47782#47782):

$$
\theta \sim \mathsf{Beta}(\alpha, \beta)
$$

this is $p(\theta)$. Notice that $\theta$ can be any real number in $[0, 1]$ interval (it is a probability), so the Bayes theorem is

$$
p(\theta|y) = \frac{p(y|\theta)\,p(\theta)}{\int_0^1 p(y|\theta)\,p(\theta)\, d\theta}
$$

So in the denominator you cannot list all the possible values and sum, since there is infinite number of possible values for $\theta$. You need to take integral, that is why we use simulation-based approaches as MCMC, to approximate those integrals.

There is also a mathematical shortcut, since beta distribution is a [conjugate prior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior) for $p$ parameter of the binomial distribution, there is a closed-form solution and the posterior distribution is available right away as

$$
\theta|y \sim \mathsf{Beta}(\alpha+y,\,\beta+n-y)
$$

this is $p(\theta|y)$.

Comment: Thanks @Tim, so θ in p(θ), p(y|θ) is same with the mean of MLE which is calculated using all the same data to get the prior?

Comment: As in https://wiseodd.github.io/techblog/2017/01/01/mle-vs-map/, it looks if the initial prior is uniform (alpha=beta=1), then it can be handled in the context of MLE.

Comment: @mon likelihood in MLE and Bayesian likelihood are technically same thing, but conceptually different, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/224037/wikipedia-entry-on-likelihood-seems-ambiguous With uniform prior $p(\theta) \propto 1$ you will get same results for MLE and MAP because it reduces to $\text{likelihood} \times 1$.

Comment: sorry again, binom.pmf(n=10,k=8,p=) for all  is the likelihood function?

Comment: @mon `binom.pmf(n=10,k=8,p=)` as a function of , so rather for "some" theta, then for "all" theta.

Comment: Thank you Tim for the follow up.

Answer (score 2):

I do not see the link here to regression, what you describe is simple posterior distribution calculation.

> Is below in Python/Scipy using (scipy.stats.binom) correct?

Yes, you implementation using scipy.stats.binom seems correct.

> Kindly explain what θ and p(y|θ) are in simple layman's English
>   without mathematical formulas. In a way a grand-ma can understand.

In probability theory and statistics, the binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $θ$ is the discrete probability distribution of the number of successes in a sequence of n independent experiments, each asking a yes–no question, and each with its own boolean-valued outcome: success/yes/true/one (with probability $θ$) or failure/no/false/zero (with probability $q = 1 − θ$). Check out the [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

$p(y|θ)$ is the likelihood function, in this case following a binomial distribution as per above. Check [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/74082/what-is-the-difference-in-bayesian-estimate-and-maximum-likelihood-estimate) out for more information. Here $y$, or sometimes $D$ corresponds to the sample set.

> Is this correct? If not, please explain why and how to get p(y|θ).

I assume you mean the posterior: $p(θ|y)$ since you have already calculated the likelihood:  $p(y|θ)$ with the `scipy.stats` function. As for the code, you are not incorporating the prior distribution (beta) here if I read it correctly. Check out this [great answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58564/help-me-understand-bayesian-prior-and-posterior-distributions/58792#58792). Following that I am hoping it will become clear that you can calculate the $numerator = beta * binomial$ by using the `scipy.stats.binom` as the priors in this case can be represented as fictitious $H$ or $T$ observations you inject to the binomial formula.